# Does anyone know of a sample script for the Barclaycard ePDQ MPI using PHP & CURL

Tags: php, curl

I'm creating a site using PHP and it has to access the Barclaycard ePDQ MPI payment interface. I've done this before using the old HSBC XML API but the Barclaycard on sees to be giving me a few headaches. The HSBC API had some pretty bad documentation and few examples so I ended up having to post an example myself (not on stackoverflow) about 2 years ago.

What I'm doing is collecting customer info from my database, taking card details that I've validated using JavaScript then PHP on the server, create an XML wrapper and post using CURL. I've had nothing but problems all morning, so does anyone know of some good examples on using the Barclaycard ePDQ payment interface?

I've set up all the requirements (SSL, etc) but so far I'm getting no response from Barclaycard. I'd rather find a good example that post various questions on this site.

Please forward any good URLs, I'm finding very little via Google.

Cheers

Comment: I suspect the reason you find nothing is because BarclayCard want to keep this not in the public domain for security reasons. I suggest you contact them in this instance unless you get generic errors back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I raised another question regards this but in the meantime.... here's the correct CURL set up you have to do...

I realise that the variables could be better and I should make this as an object but I just want to get a quick answer up there. The script also needs to sift through the different accept and error messages but this is what I've got so far...

```
$ch = curl_init();
$url = "https://secure2.epdq.co.uk:11500"; // Don't need to add curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_PORT, 443); as port is included
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $vars); // $vars is your XML 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

$xml = new domDocument;
$xml->loadXML($data);

if (!$xml) {
    echo 'Error while parsing the document - Please Contact to determine if payment has gone though';
    exit;
}

$x = $xml->getElementsByTagName( "CcErrCode" );
$approved = $x->item(0)->nodeValue;

$xx = $xml->getElementsByTagName( "CcReturnMsg" );
$CcReturnMsg = $xx->item(0)->nodeValue;

if($approved) {

// the card is valid.
    $y = $xml->getElementsByTagName( "Id" );
    $BCardId = $y->item(1)->nodeValue;

    $z = $xml->getElementsByTagName( "MessageList" );
    $MessageList = $z->item(0)->nodeValue;

    $zz = $xml->getElementsByTagName( "AvsRespCode" );
    $AvsRespCode = $zz->item(0)->nodeValue;

    $zzz = $xml->getElementsByTagName( "AvsDisplay" );
    $AvsDisplay = $zzz->item(0)->nodeValue;

    $zzzz = $xml->getElementsByTagName( "ProcReturnMsg" );
    $ProcReturnMsg = $zzzz->item(0)->nodeValue;

     if($approved == "1"){
       echo "approved!<br />";
       echo "BCardId: " . $BCardId . ", MessageList=" . $MessageList . ", " . $AvsRespCode . ", " . $AvsDisplay . ", " . $ProcReturnMsg;
       die();
     }else{
       // raise that it's been partially accepted, 
       echo "partially approved";
       echo "BCardId: " . $BCardId . ", MessageList=" . $MessageList . ", " . $AvsRespCode . ", " . $AvsDisplay . ", " . $ProcReturnMsg;
       die();
     }

}else{
   echo "you have been completely knocked back";
   $zzzzz = $xml->getElementsByTagName( "Text" );
   $BCard_Text = $zzzzz->item(0)->nodeValue;
   echo "The reason:" . $BCard_Text;    
   die();
}
```

hope this helps other people who have to set this up!